# How to migrate the volumes of a Docker-Compose Postgres to another host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker Compose file with some services. One of them is the database which I would like to back up the volumes and migrate all the data to another machine.
My docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
  ...
  serviceN:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - postgresnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    postgresql:
    postgresql_data:

networks:
    postgresnet:
        driver: bridge
```

How could I backup the data of postgresql and postgresql_data volunes and migrate them to another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to share external volumes between your `docker-compose` files.

First create volume

```
docker volume create shared-data
```

Next modify you `yml`:

```
...
volumes:
    postgresql:
    postgresql_data:
      external:
        name: shared-data
...
```

Now your `postgresql_data` is mapped to external volume and everything you save there could be visible from outside. Just create same configuration in another `docker-compose.yml` and enjoy.